# Ad Gallery Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have the following code to enable Fancybox to work with the jQuery Ad-Gallery plugin - The Ad gallery displays thumbnails and a main image which changes when selecting a different thumbnail.

At the moment, clicking on the larger image triggers fancybox but it is not possible to navigate through the other images within the gallery. I have tried adding a class and rel to all of the images within the gallery but this doesn't do anything? I think because the larger image is only loaded from the gallery when the thumbnail is clicked so possibly fancybox cannot find the next image to display? Is there any way to force fancybox to load the next image in the gallery/thumbnail list?

Thanks in advance

```
<div id="gallery" class="ad-gallery">
<div class="ad-image-wrapper"></div>
<div class="ad-nav">
<div class="ad-thumbs">

<ul class="ad-thumb-list">
<li class="list-thumb">
<a href="/image1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
<img src="/image1.jpg"  alt="" class="image" />
</a>
</li>

<li class="list-thumb">
<a href="/image2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">
<img src="/image2.jpg"  alt="" class="image" />
</a>
</li>

</ul></div></div></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var galleries = $('.ad-gallery').adGallery();
});
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).on("click", ".ad-image", 
 function()  
{
$.fancybox.open({
href : $(this).find("img").attr("src"),
closeBtn: false,
closeClick : true,
openEffect : 'elastic',
openSpeed  : 450,
closeEffect : 'elastic',
closeSpeed  : 450,
});
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to build the fancybox gallery manually outside adGallery and/or fancybox. Then fire fancybox from within an adGallery callback like :

```
var fancyGallery = []; // define gallery group
jQuery(function ($) {
    // create fancybox gallery
    $(".ad-thumb-list").find("a").each(function (i) {
        // create each item of the gallery
        var item = {
            href: this.href,
            // if captions are from alt attribute in img tag
            title: typeof $(this).find("img").attr("alt") !== "undefined" ? $(this).find("img").attr("alt") : ""
            // optionally, if captions are from title attribute in a tag
            // title : this.title ? this.title : ""
        };
        // push each item into the gallery group
        fancyGallery.push(item);
    }); // each
    $('.ad-gallery').adGallery({
        callbacks: {
            afterImageVisible: function () {
                // open fancybox programmatically once the adGallery is ready
                var fancyIndex = this.current_index; // matches adGallery active thumb 
                $(".ad-image").on("click", function () {
                    $.fancybox(fancyGallery, {
                        // starts gallery from active thumb
                        index: fancyIndex,
                        // optional : title inside fancybox
                        helpers: {
                            title: {
                                type: "inside"
                            }
                        }
                    }); // fancybox
                    return false;
                }); // on click
            } // afterImageVisible
        } // callbacks
    }); // adGallery
}); // ready
```

**NOTES** :

- we need fancybox `index` API option to select what element the gallery starts from
- `.on()` requires jQuery v1.7+
- this code is for fancybox v2.x. Use the proper fancybox API options for v1.3.4

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EQh76/show/)**